# How do I run a function whenever any image in the grid is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, I have blocks of images called product that reside in a 'product grid'.

Each group has different values, though they are entered statically now, I imagine in the future they would each be added through some sort of adapter. In this case, only classes were defined, not ID's.

How do I make it so that when an image is clicked, wherever it is on the grid, I would be able to retrieve the:

1. Product Name (product_title)
2. Product Price (product_price)
3. The image source (images/product7.jpg); and send it to the next page?

For one thing, I know that if an id is set, you can get the attributes within like value. How is the javascript written when the data is not in a single tag/element like below? Moreover, supposing I do not have id's defined, how do i get the data only from the "group" of elements associated to the image clicked? Each "Block" basically has the same classes.

Is defining an ID for each copy unavoidable in this scenario?

---

This is what one block would look like, copied several times:

```
        <!-- Product -->
        <div class="product">
            <div class="product_image" value="Yellow"><img  src="images/product_7.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div class="product_extra product_new"><a href="categories.html">New</a></div>
            <div class="product_content">
                <div class="product_title"><a href="product.html">Yellow Phone</a></div>
                <div class="product_price">$670</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

all inside a

```
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">

                    <div class="product_grid">
```

Each copy have the same classes defined, only differing in the innerhtml values like price. These values are then sent into another page to do stuff.

Comment: what about using data- attributes? https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jquery, you could do something like this:

```
var $productImages = $('.product_image > img');
$productImages.click(function(){
     var $this =  $(this);
     var $product = $this.parents('.product');

     var title = $product.find('.product_title > a').text();
     var price = $product.find('.product_price').text();
     var imgSource = $this.attr('src')

     // all values are here, now you can do whatever you want with them

    alert(`Title is ${title}, price is ${price} and image source is ${imgSource}`);

})
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a fiddle about from what I was able to understand (using jquery):
https://jsfiddle.net/nv4ezjgc/

Actually this is pretty basic.
The jquery part looks like this

```
$('.product_grid').on('click', 'img', function(){
    var url = 'your-site.html';
    var el = $(this).parents('.product');
    var params = {
        title: el.find('.product_title').text(),
        price: el.find('.product_price').text(),
        img_src: el.find('.product_image img').attr('src')
    };
    window.location.href = url+'?title='+params['title']+'&price='+params['price']+'&img_src='+params['img_src'];
});
```

I don't know how you want to pass the arguments to a new site. **Passing prices etc. for a shop system via the url (or js in general) is unsafe.** Instead you should pass an ID to get the data from the server.